# How to upload files using relative path at Selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium, testing, google-chrome-extension, selenium-ide, functional-testing

I'm trying to upload a file at Selenium IDE using relative path but it didn't work. I really tried some approachs like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33986074/selenium-ide-path-of-file-to-be-uploaded-is-to-be-made-relative?answertab=active#tab-top)

This way works:

[image]

But what I want to do is something like this:

[image]

I need it because I need to send these test files to run in another computer without have to edit the `.side` files. Anyone knows commands, scripts, or any other method that I could try at Selenium IDE?

Comment: Can you try `send keys` instead of `type` ?

Comment: not sure it helps you, but you can send a local machine's file path to a remote webdriver... there's a specific way to do that.  https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/remote/index_exports_FileDetector.html

Comment: thanks all you, @pcalkins and @Naveen, but I really want to know a way to do this without using Selenium webdriver solutions like `send keys` or `FileDetector`. I really need to use Selenium IDE and pass it to another person to execute (So, I can't execute remotely too).

Comment: I believe the browser will require an absolute path.  I'm not familiar with Selenium IDE, but in Java you could build the paths yourself using things like  System.getProperty("user.home")...